# How to prevent repeated Firefox password requests when I don't want to login?

Tags: firefox, passwords

I use a Firefox master password, so every time I visit a site with saved credentials, it prompts me for that, which is fine if I want to login. Sometimes, however, I don't want to do anything that requires a login (say, read a forum, not post) and then it is really annoying to get repeated prompts for the master password each time I change the page on the site (e.g. when I see the next page in a forum thread).

Is there a way to let Firefox remember that I don't want to login this time and that it displays the password request only once?

Answer (score 0):

The master password is typically only prompted upon starting up the app. So if you put in your master password it'll keep you logged in for the rest of the time your browser is open. If you keep declining to put in the master password it'll keep popping up because it keeps encountering new instances of places you have saved logins and keep prompting you, hence your feeling that you're being hounded by Firefox.

If there are sites you don't want to save passwords for, just go to Preferences>Security>Saved Passwords and delete the passwords you don't want saved.

Comment: The problem is that *most of the time* I want to use my account but *sometimes* I don't. Also, it occurs not only for new places but for the same website over and over again, that is my problem.